# Calling a function too many times in a while loop

Tags: c, string, function, loops

The function `char** read(char file[])` is supposed to return an array of strings, and every string represents a Json object extracted from a json file.

The `char* Purge(char S[], int n)` removes `' '` (spaces), `'"'`,`','`,`'\t'`from a string (extracted from the json file).

The main problem is this first statement in the while loop `seBuffer = Purge(Buffer, strlen(Buffer) + 1);` it uses the Purge function way too many times, and for characters that have already been checked for, and it happens the whole way from the beginning to the end of one json object, is that something I should be worried about ? or is there another way that's probably more efficient ?

```
char** read(char file[])
{
    FILE* pF = fopen(file, "r");

    if(pF == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char Buffer[MAX], oJson[MAX], c;
    char* seBuffer;
    int nbOJ = 0, toAllocate = 0;
    
    while((c = fgetc(pF)) != EOF)
        if(c == '{')
            nbOJ++;
    
    Size = nbOJ;

    rewind(pF);

    char** ObjectsJson = (char**)malloc(nbOJ*sizeof(char*));
    nbOJ = -1;

    while(fgets(Buffer, MAX, pF))
    {
        seBuffer = Purge(Buffer, strlen(Buffer) + 1);

        if(seBuffer[0] == '[' || seBuffer[0] == ']')
            continue;

        if(seBuffer[0] == '{')
        {
            oJson[0] = 0;
            nbOJ++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(seBuffer[0] == '}')
        {
            ObjectsJson[nbOJ] = (char*)malloc((toAllocate+1)*sizeof(char));

            strcpy(ObjectsJson[nbOJ], oJson);
            toAllocate = 0;

            continue;
        }
        
        toAllocate += strlen(seBuffer);
        sprintf(oJson, "%s%s", oJson, seBuffer);
    }
    free(seBuffer);
    fclose(pF);
    return ObjectsJson;
}
```

Comment: The question is confusing. So you benchmarked the code and that function call is the slowest part of the program?

Comment: No, I didn't. the function gets used way too many times, and my gut tells me there is a more efficient way. so you're saying, if it's fast enough, we don't really care about the approach ?

Comment: I mean, why is it a problem if the function is called too many times? You call `fgets` that many times as well.

Comment: If the code already works you can ask on [codereview.se] too (read there help center before asking)

Comment: _If_ `Purge` does a `malloc` on _each_ call, you are _leaking_ memory. That's because you are only doing a _single_ `free(seBuffer)` _after_ the end of the loop. You need to do one on _each_ loop iteration, corresponding to each allocation from `Purge`

Comment: (by the way you didn't include a [example]. Where did the `Purge` function come from?)

Comment: Besides what do you mean by "for characters that have already been checked for"? I see that `buffer` contains new content each time?

Comment: `fgets`  doesn't loop around the string, whereas `Purge` has to check the whole string, and that whole string + the new character, so not only it's looping around it but also checking for characters that have already been checked for...

Comment: A speedy solution for `Purge` may be to _not_ allocate a new buffer, since the caller never uses `Buffer` after the call. Just have `Purge` do its magic "in-place" [it may have to copy the original data to its own stack based temp buffer and copy back the cleaned up results]. Then, caller can use the passed down `Buffer` [instead of `seBuffer`] that has been cleaned.

Comment: @BeyondCrisp I don't understand what you mean. Each time through the loop fgets reads exactly one line from the file.  Purge takes that one line and does what it does.  At no point does Purge work on something it worked on from a previous loop iteration because each time it is called there is a new line from the file.  So how can it be checking things it checked before?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Oh you're right, my bad. I somehow thought that it adds one character at a time to the string, until newline. I guess it takes the whole line.

Comment: @CraigEstey if you will, can you please write down a quick sample of the code you're insinuating, so I can clearly understand your idea

Comment: In order to do that I would need to see your original code [for `Purge`], so please _edit_ your question and post it in a code block.

Comment: @CraigEstey here is a link: https://onlinegdb.com/xno4YXxw4

Answer (score 0):

This is prefaced by the top comments re. in-place modification and memory leaks.

Because `Purge` only removes some chars, it can do this in-place. So, no need for either `strlen` or `malloc` at all. See below ...

---

There were some issues with your `Purge` code.

In your original code below, the caller of `Purge` does a `strlen` and passes that as the 2nd argument. `Purge` then does its own `strlen`, overwriting/discarding the caller's value.

`Purge` prescans the input string once to get the number/count of chars to be elided.

This is so the amount given to `malloc` can be reduced. But, for this use case, just using the original length is better because it saves an extra scan for what is largely a nicety.

But, if we did really want to use `malloc` on the shortened list, and do the prescan, the prescan loop can count both the number of chars to elide *and* the string length at the same time in a single pass. So, all separate `strlen` calls would be superfluous.

So, in the original code, the string buffer was scanned a total of *four* times.

---

Here is the original code for your `Purge` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
Purge(char S[], int n)
{
    // ETVG = Espace , tabulation, virgule, guillemet
    int nbETVG = 0, j = 0;

    n = strlen(S);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (S[i] == ' ' || S[i] == '\t' || S[i] == ',' || S[i] == '"')
            nbETVG++;

    int m = n - nbETVG;
    char *SE = (char *) malloc(m * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (S[i] == ' ' || S[i] == '\t' || S[i] == ',' || S[i] == '"')
            continue;

        SE[j] = S[i];
        j++;
    }

    return SE;
}

void
main()
{
    char *Pstr;
    char str[] = { "this , is a       test  ." };
    Pstr = Purge(str, strlen(str));
    printf("%s", Pstr);
}
```

---

Here is the refactored `Purge` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
Purge(char *src)
{
    char *dst = src;

    for (int chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++) {
        switch (chr) {
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case ',':
        case '"':
            break;
        default:
            *dst++ = chr;
            break;
        }
    }

    *dst = 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char str[] = { "this , is a       test  ." };

    printf("%s\n", str);
    Purge(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```